# Trying to conditionally add a column to a pandas dataframe from another related dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm brand new to using pandas, and I've tried searching for a solution to this (what seems to be simple) problem. I'm trying to conditionally add a column to some of the rows of one dataframe from another dataframe. Here's my data:

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Acme ID':["A-123","A-345","A-678"],
        'Active':['Y','N','Y'],
        'Other Col':["some","other","data"]})  

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Acme ID':["A-123","A-678"],
        'Active Date':['2020-05-15','2020-07-20']})
```

I'm trying to add the Active Date from df_2 to all rows in df_1 where the Active flag is 'Y'. The items in df_2 can join to the items in df_1 using the Acme ID column. Here's what I would expect the resulting dataframe to look like:

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Acme ID':["A-123","A-345","A-678"],
        'Active':['Y','N','Y'],
        'Other Col':["some","other","data"],
        'Active Date':['2020-05-15',pd.NaT,'2020-07-20']})
```

I've tried a number of different approaches like just iterating through df_1 (but I keep getting SettingWithCopyWarning) and I figure there's a better way. I've also tried using some of the other operations like `assign`, but they don't seem to like that the dataframes are different lengths. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `df_1.merge(df_2, on='Acme ID', how='left')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@It_is_Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65722330/trying-to-conditionally-add-a-column-to-a-pandas-dataframe-from-another-related#comment116201752_65722330), `df_1.merge(df_2, on='Acme ID', how='left')` was what I was looking for. I thought I had tried something similar to that, but guess not.